# run and install a service from within an app

Tags: android, android-service

hello i've searched throughtly for an answer to this and could'nt find anything that is helpfull. 
i'm making an android service and i want to distirbute it to clients.
the problem is that some client wants to write an app that will use the service and some clients want to get the complete package an app + service .

i want the user to basically download one link and that my app will install the service on the device and then use it .
i don't want multiple confirmations for every service/app i want one download and then install.

i've tried two solutions which didn't work for me .

one is to get the exact location of the app and then use an intent to run and install it.
the problem is that the user is getting a conformation for each app/service.

the second was adb shell command to install multiple apps .
that also just didnt work because of permissons.

is there any way to install and then run my own service from an my own app.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i don't want multiple confirmations for every service/app i want one download and then install

This is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices or via ROM mods, for obvious security reasons. The user is involved in any APK installation.

Comment: ok thank you , is  there any possible way to transform a service to a lib/jar or in some sort of android fashion and include it in my app?

Comment: @Chenshov: An Android `Service` must be registered in a manifest of an installed APK. So, at compile time, your `Service` could come from a JAR or Android library project, but it then needs to be compiled into the app.